# How to keep track of values in EditText inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Sorry if I didn't choose a clear title for the question. here's the situation. I have to implement below screen which takes product names over network.

[image]

Those 3 white rectangles have 3 EditText which can be edited by user. If any one of those 3 EditText in one Item edited by user I want to store that object in different ArrayList.(Each list item represent by product object).

For example think user edited value for "Alzel 400mg".When user search for product start with "Al" by using another network call relevant data will be taken and apply to this list view after clearing old list. After that process I want to display "Alzel 400mg" product with that user entered value earlier. To do this I need to keep track of all user edited products and compare them with new ones and make relevant updates to object and apply to list view.

I hope you guys understand what I want to achieve. since I have approximately 12000 products I'm not taking all products at ones. I'm getting only 20 at a time and add them to ResylerView.

Here's the Adapter for listView.

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Products> listData;
    private ArrayList<Products> editedData;
    private Context context;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private static final int ITEM = 0;
    private static final int LOADING = 1;
    private static final int QUANTITY = 5;
    private static final int FREE_QUANTITY = 10;
    private static final int DISCOUNT = 15;

    //private String[] quantitiy1Data;

    public ProductListAdapter(ArrayList<Products> listData, Context context) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
        editedData = new ArrayList<>();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public ArrayList<Products> getListData() {
        return listData;
    }

    public ArrayList<Products> getEditedData() {
        return editedData;
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<Products> data) {
        this.listData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return listData.get(position) == null ? LOADING : ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM:
                viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
                break;
            case LOADING:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new LoadingVH(v2);
                break;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Products productObject = listData.get(position);

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case ITEM:
                String productName = productObject.getProductName();
                String quantityValue = productObject.getQuantity();
                String freeQuantityValue = productObject.getFreeQuantity();
                String discountValue = productObject.getDiscount();
                ContentViewHolder movieVH = (ContentViewHolder) holder;
                movieVH.productName.setText(productName);

                movieVH.quantityEditTextListener.updatePosition(movieVH.getLayoutPosition());
                movieVH.quantity.setText(quantityValue);

                movieVH.freeQuantityEditTextListener.updatePosition(movieVH.getLayoutPosition());
                movieVH.freeQuantity.setText(freeQuantityValue);

                movieVH.discountEditTextListener.updatePosition(movieVH.getLayoutPosition());
                movieVH.discount.setText(discountValue);

                movieVH.quantity.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                break;
            case LOADING:
                //Do nothing
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData == null ? 0 : listData.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_product_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ContentViewHolder(view, new MyCustomEditTextListener()
                , new MyCustomEditTextListener(), new MyCustomEditTextListener());
        return viewHolder;
    }

    /**
     * View holder for main container
     */
    public class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView productName;
        private EditText quantity;
        private EditText freeQuantity;
        private EditText discount;
        private MyCustomEditTextListener quantityEditTextListener;
        private MyCustomEditTextListener freeQuantityEditTextListener;
        private MyCustomEditTextListener discountEditTextListener;


        public ContentViewHolder(View itemView, MyCustomEditTextListener textListener
                , MyCustomEditTextListener textListener2, MyCustomEditTextListener textListener3) {

            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name_data);
            quantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_1_edit_text);
            freeQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_2_edit_text);
            discount = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_3_edit_text);

            quantityEditTextListener = textListener;
            quantityEditTextListener.setEditTextType(QUANTITY);

            freeQuantityEditTextListener = textListener2;
            freeQuantityEditTextListener.setEditTextType(FREE_QUANTITY);

            discountEditTextListener = textListener3;
            discountEditTextListener.setEditTextType(DISCOUNT);

            this.quantity.addTextChangedListener(quantityEditTextListener);
            this.freeQuantity.addTextChangedListener(freeQuantityEditTextListener);
            this.discount.addTextChangedListener(discountEditTextListener);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) {
                //itemClickListener.onItemClick(v,this.getLayoutPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * View holder to display loading list item
     */
    protected class LoadingVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LoadingVH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    /**
     * textWatcher for to keep track of changed data.
     */
    private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
        private int position;
        private int type;

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;

        }

        public void setEditTextType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            // no op
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            if (type == QUANTITY) {
                listData.get(position).setQuantity(charSequence.toString());

            } else if (type == FREE_QUANTITY) {
                listData.get(position).setFreeQuantity(charSequence.toString());

            } else if (type == DISCOUNT) {
                listData.get(position).setDiscount(charSequence.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }


    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View v, int position);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have Implemented TextWatcher class to prevent entered value dispersing form list Items when scrolling. I should be able to use `onTextChanged` to add change object to new Array list but it stated to duplicate values in array list. Also some how that method is triggered when list initially loading which make it hard to achieve what I want. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplication, you may want to use a [HashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)/[HashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of ArrayList for storing the edited items.

Comment: using hashmap in android is very expensive and will be avoided whenever possible. Could you suggest some other approach to solve this problem